# getExtras always null?

Tags: android, bundle

My app design little bit different..

`Activity--> Activity---> B ----> Activity c ---- Activity D` after that it should go like

```
ActvityD--> Activity A
```

In Activity D:

```
                 Intent intent= new Intent(D.this,A.class);
                Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(Constant.AB , "ABCD");
                intent.putExtras(bundle);


                 startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity A

Onstart

```
   Intent intent= getIntent();

    Bundle extras =intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
        String val = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constant.AB);

        if(val.equals("ABCD")){
            m_myApp.getCurrentPlaybackHelper(1);
            Log.e(TAG,"Remote play is working");
        }
    }
```

the extras always be null.did i miss anything?

Comment: if A is already started, may be look into `onNewIntent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As njzk2 already pointed out, Activity A will receive the new Intent with your extras only in `onNewIntent()`. The `getIntent()` method however will still return the original intent used to start the Activity in the first place.

So try moving your logic from `onStart()` to `onNewIntent()` (using the intent passed into the method) and you should have the Extras there.